# Best approach of Creating String Object

Tags: java, string, performance, objectinstantiation

In `java` we can create `String` in the following 2 ways -

```
String str1 = new String("first string");  //1

String str2 = "second string";  //2
```

Is there any difference in performance  with these 2 approaches? And in the second case is there any new `String` object created?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach forces the creation of a new `String` object. The second allows java to use the constant from the string pool, and should generally be preferred.

Comment: so for using constant from the string pool there might be the constant already in the string pool? If the constant is not available in the string pool?